Notation: Are all the quantities "multiplied" by a differential operator its arguments?
In a book about the Fokker-Planck equation by Hannes Risken, he writes the master equation for a probability distribution over x as
$\partial W(x,t)/\partial t = \int [w(x'\rightarrow x)W(x',t)-w(x\rightarrow x')W(x,t)]dx'$
where $w(x'\rightarrow x)$ is the transition probability. Then he defines it as
$w(x'\rightarrow x)=\left[ -\frac{\partial}{\partial x} D^{(1)}(x) + \frac{\partial ^{2}}{\partial x^{2}} D^{(2)}(x)\right]\delta (x-x')$
Do the differential operators apply to the products of the D functions and the delta function outside the brackets, or just the D functions?

To the product of the $D$ and  delta functions.
